# Login page not redirect to another page using header function

Tags: php, html

Good Day PHP wizards,

I would like to ask help from all of you. It seems my Log-in button does not direct to Home (Student_Home.php). Student ID and password has been registered to database already.

***Here is the script for Student_login.php***

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() 
{
    if(document.form1.student_id.value=="")
    {
      alert("Please enter your login Id.");
      document.form1.student_id.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if(document.form1.student_password.value=="")
    {
      alert("Please enter your password.");
      document.form1.student_password.focus();
      return false;
    }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: #0099FF;
}
-->
</style></head>
<body onLoad="javascript:document.form1.student_id.focus()">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Student_login_handler.php" onSubmit="return validate();">
  <table width="100%" height="100%" >
    <tr>
      <td height="15%"><?php include 'Header.php';?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" height="80%" align="center" valign="baseline"><table width="90%" >
        <tr>
          <td width="8%"><a href="index.php" class="stylelink" style="text-decoration:none; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;, Times, serif;">Home</a></td>
          <td width="35%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="27%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="30%" align="right"><a href="Student_Registration.php" class="stylelink" style="text-decoration:none ; font-weight: bold;">New Student Click Here</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

          <?php if(!empty($_GET['flag']) && $_GET['flag'] == "success") { ?>
          <tr>
               <td class="stylegreen" colspan="4" align="center">Congratulations! You Are successfully registered. You can use your Login Id and Password to login to your account.</td>
          </tr>
          <?php 
          }
          else if(!empty($_GET['flag']) && $_GET['flag'] == "exists") { ?>
          <tr>
               <td class="stylered" colspan="4" align="center">This Login Id( <?=$_GET['student_id']?>) already exists.Please, try again with another Login Id</td>
          </tr>
          <?php 
            }else if(!empty($_GET['flag']) && $_GET['flag'] == "error") {
          ?>
            <tr>
               <td class="stylered" colspan="4" align="center">Error while inserting data. Please, try again.</td>
          </tr>
          <?php
            }
          ?>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4"><table width="30%"  border="1" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <tr align="center" bgcolor="#999999">
              <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CC33" class="stylebig">Student Login Here</td>
                </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1" class="stylesmall">
              <td width="35%" align="left" class="style7">Login Id : </td>
                <td width="65%" align="left"><input name="student_id" type="text" id="student_id"></td>
              </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1" class="stylesmall">
              <td align="left" class="style7">Password:</td>
                <td align="left"><input name="student_password" type="password" id="student_password"></td>
              </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1">



              <td colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;
                <?php if(!empty($_GET['flag']) && $_GET['flag'] == "invalid") { ?>
                <span class="stylered">Invalid Login Id or Password</span>
                <?php }?>               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
              <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="login" class="style10" type="submit" id="login" value="Login">
                <input name="close" type="button" id="close" class="style10" value="Close" onClick="self.location='index.php'">                </td>
                </tr>
          </table></td>
          </tr>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="5%" align="center"><?php include 'Footer.php';?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

***and here is also the Student_login_handler codes***

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'Connect.php';
    $flag = "";
    $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
    $student_password =  $_POST['student_password'];
    $query = "select last_login_date from student_information where student_id='$student_id' and student_password='$student_password' and student_status ='Enable'";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$link_id);
    if(mysql_error() != null){
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    if($date = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $lastdate = $date['last_login_date'];
         $date2 = date("d-m-Y h:i A",strtotime($lastdate));
         $_SESSION['student_id'] = $_POST['student_id'];
         $_SESSION['lastlogin'] =$date2;
         $_SESSION['type'] = "Student";
         mysql_query("update student_information set last_login_date=now() where student_id='$student_id'",$link_id);
         if(mysql_error() != null){
            die(mysql_error());
        }
         header("location:Student_Home.php");
         die();
    }
    else
    {
        $flag = "invalid";
        header("location:Student_login.php?flag=$flag");
        die();      
    } 

?>
```

*****It keeps saying "Invalid ID or password"

Hope you can help me troubleshoot this..

Comment: Keep it short and tidy we don't need to see your entire HTML.

Comment: Maybe replace `if(!empty($_GET['flag']) && $_GET['flag'] == "invalid")` with `if(isset($_GET['flag']) && $_GET['flag'] == "invalid")`? But as I see, empty should also check it. Then never mind, looking further.

Comment: Try `var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result));` after `$result = mysql_query($query,$link_id);` and see if there are actually results.

Comment: @Michal
hello Michal,, sorry for that,,im just newbie in PHP i thought everything can help. I'll try your suggestions when i come home later. Please keep posted.

Answer (score 0):

I already got this problem, probably `header()` function not work. Anywhere following are two solution to solve this problem,

#### Solution 1

Using PHP  you can just add **[ob_start();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)** function on first line of your starting **php**.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    .....
    .....
```

#### Solution 2

Using JavaScript to redirect **Student_Home.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       window.navigate("http://www.url.com/Student_Home.php");
</script>
```

another JavaScript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.location="http://www.url.com/Student_Home.php";
</script>
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thank you Jay Patel..i'll try it later.. i'll see what happen. Please keep posted.